# How to specify the prop as optional using reactjs and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have a parent component and reusable component. I use this reusable component within parent component twice. I  pass boolean prop visible to one of the reusable component. Doing so, within reusable component pycharm throws error "prop visible doesnt exist on type propswithchilren"

below is the code,

```
function ParentComponent () {
    return (
        <LeftBlock>
            <ReusableComponent visible={true}/>
         </LeftBlock>
         <RightBlock>
             <ReusableComponent/>
         </RightBlock>
    )
}


const ReusableComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
    visible, //this is where i get pycharm error.
}) => {
    return (
        //other logic
    )
}
```

How do i specify this visible prop is optional as you see visible prop is passed only in leftblock and not from right block. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this by using `interface` in typescript. Implementing the `?` operator indicates the props are optional.

```
interface PropsNeeded{
   visible?: boolean
}

const ReusableComponent: React.FC<PropsNeeded> = (props) => {
    return (
       //other logic
    )
}
```

Comment: I think you should not destructure ```visible``` in your reusable component, instead try pass only ```props``` in it

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning default value to prop

```
interface TestProps {
visible?: boolean;
}


 const Test = ({visible : false}: TestProps) => {
    return (
       <p>
          {visible}
       </p>
    );
 }
```